# Search for an element with a specific content?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Assuming I have the following HTML code:

```
...
<p>bla bla</p>
<h3>Foobar</h3>
<p>bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla</p>
<h3>Example</h3>
...
```

Is there a way to fetch the first `h3` element which contains the text `Foobar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`contains()` XPath function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains):

```ruby
doc.xpath("//h3[contains(text(), 'Foobar')]")
```

Or if the target text could be in a descendent text node of `h3`, use:

```ruby
doc.xpath("//h3[contains(.//text(), 'Foobar')]")
```

To fetch the first matching element directly rather than an array, use [`at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath) rather than [`xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath).

Answer (score 2):

Since this is HTML, I would recommend CSS selectors:

```ruby
puts doc.at_css('h3:contains("Foobar")')

#=> <h3>Foobar</h3>
```

CSS selectors tend to make for more readable expressions when parsing HTML. I tend to use XPath only for XML or when I need the full power of XPath expressions.

Comment: HTML or XML, either way, CSS selectors are more readable than XPath the majority of the time. XPath has more functionality though.